# Error "COMPILE_SDK_VERSION" not found when adding a GPUImage Library to the Project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gpuimage

Previously I worked on Eclipse for Android Development, but I have now moved to Android Studio for a specific project and also I wanted to get a hang of Android Studio.

I created a new Project. And then imported a new module to add the library for "GPUImage" from the "Project Explorer". The library got added, but when I compiled the project, I got this

Error : `"Error:(4, 0) Could not find property 'COMPILE_SDK_VERSION' on com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension_Decorated@171c6271."`

Tried to follow some tutorials but haven't been able to find any thing. It must be something related to editing the gradle files of the app or library but not sure. Need Help. Thanks!

Comment: What build.gradle file for the lib? Is that sdk instslled, avail to AS?

Answer (score 0):

If you import as module, you should download released version:
https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage/releases
But in my opinion, add by gradle is better

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage:gpuimage-library:1.3.0'
}
```